# Flex tile list component takes time to render all the Items

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

To create a similar page http://wireless.amazon.com/b/684177011/ref=topnav_br_ph?ie=UTF8&class=link  in Flex what are all the basic component involved , just high level is enough here is the template I guess looks like

```
<VBox>
 <comp:Header/>
 <HBox>
  <comp:SearchLeft/>
  //Load all the products in the tile List  
  <TileList/>
 </HBox>
</VBox>
```

By Loading all the products into the tile List which takes lot of time to render the whole page , how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For the "Narrow by" sections; I'd probably use some lists with itemRenderers that display check boxes.

For the phone display, I'd use a TileList, which it sounds like you're already using.

A TextInput and a Label for the search box.  An Image for the logo.  LinkButtons for some of the linksup top.

You can optimize a TileList renderer's time by optimizing your renderers.  Without seeing the Renderer code, I'm not sure how to help you with that though.

Comment: My renderer is pretty similar to the one in that URL a VBOX with two child one is Label & image component. the problem I have is , If the tile List height is less than 480px all the Items are loaded very fast but when I increase the Tile list to height according to number of items (data source ) then my app is taking lot of time to show up. 
Am rendering totally 90 devices in the tile list and I want to show them all in one container so that I will get scroll to the whole application.

Comment: @Anandh You'll have to show us code.  IF you are rendering 90 devices; that sounds like a cause for the slow down.  A list class only renders what is on screen, which is usually a raction of what is in your dataProvider.  I have solved many memory issues for clients by re-writing their itemRenderers.  I suspect you may gain efficiency by doing the same, but I can't say for certain w/o reviewing code.

Comment: I totally understand any Flex list based component render only items which are visible in the viewable area , actually my problem is I want to render/show all the items in my view. My code works perfect when my List component size is 640x480 , Am getting a vertical scroll but now I went into a scenario where I want to render all the items in the screen and also want the vertical scroll to the whole application rather than scrolling List component,I that ways I can scroll my left hand side "Narrow by" selections.For sure I will share my code with you,please let me know you IM.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Anandh I'm sorry.  I didn't mean I want to share your code w/ me personally.  I meant I Want you to add code and/or links to runnable samples as part of the question.  If you want my personal help, you can give me a call www.asktheflexpert.com